# 'mat-expansion-panel' is not a known element when making build for production in angular 5

Tags: angular-material, angular5, production

I am using lazy loading in my Angular 5 project and I have imported 'mat-expansion-panel' in one of the module.
'mat-expansion-panel' is working fine in development mode but when I make build for production it shows error that 'mat-expansion-panel' is not a known element without showing any line number.

I searched everywhere but didn't found anything.

Answer (score 14):

Add this to your AppModule

```
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
```

and then add 'MatExpansionModule' to your module's imports

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I have imported correctly the module in AppModule, and the functionality works like a charm, but the compiler fails when building for production

Comment: In my case, I had to add 
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
 in shared.module.ts and MatExpansionModule to imports:[] array and exports: [] array of shared.module.ts     I am On Angular 10